# How can I change this so the user can type their directory and get rid of the byte error?

Tags: python

```
import zipfile

try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile("daysv2.zip") as file:
        file.extractall(pwd='abc123')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("Extraction was successful")
```

How can I change this so that the user can type their directory and the password? Also how would I fix this error of

```
pwd: expected bytes, got str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwd` must be a `bytes` object, which is written/indicated such as `b'abc123'`. Or more generically:

```py
bytes('abc123', 'UTF-8') # For UTF-8 encoded string -> bytes
```

Comment: How can i change it so that the user types in the directory of the file and the password

Comment: @SavarJ, it is called [input(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: I know that. Would I just save the input and put it in the zipfile.Zipfile() function?

Comment: Something like `file = input('Enter a file..')` and `password = input('Enter the password...')`, and then you can do `with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as f: f.extractall(pwd=bytes(password, 'utf-8'))` should do